# CKeditor copy inline widget from editable widget (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am facing a problem in CKeditor (4.8.0) copy/paste on firefox for inline widget inside editable widget. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmyb5L7s/4/)

I want to copy both text and inline widget from the editable part of another widget :
[image]

But when i am pasting it only the start of the text is copied until the widget start :

[image]

This is working on Chrome

Html :

```
<textarea id="editor">foo bar
<div class='mywidget'>
<div>Header</div>
<div class='mywidget_contents'>
  <p>test copy <span class="cke_placeholder">[[it]]</span> please<br></p>
</div>
</div>
</textarea>
```

Javascript :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mywidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'mywidget',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'mywidget', {
            button: "My Widget",
            template:"<div class='mywidget'><div>Header</div><div class='mywidget_contents'></div></div>",
            editables: {
                content: {
                    selector: '.mywidget_contents'
                }
            },
            upcast: function (element) {
              return element.hasClass('mywidget');
            }
        } );
    }
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraPlugins: 'mywidget,placeholder'
} );
```

Did someone find a workaround for this ?

Comment: It sounds like a bug. I report it here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1349.